# Can't get the model relationship right. It said property doesn't exist in Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel

Something is wrong with my codes. I knew my concept is right in my own thinking but not working....I want to take out the videos that logged in user liked. 
This is my liked table and it stored amv_id and user_id

```
Schema::create('like_videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId("amv_id");
        $table->foreignId("user_id");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is my amv table and it stored everything of videos

```
Schema::create('amvs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('desc');
        $table->integer('view');
        $table->integer('like');
        $table->integer('dislike');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->string('video');
        $table->string('thumb');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is my user table and it stored user infos

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('sub');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('suspend');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is my controller codes

```
public function likedvideo() {
    $id = auth()->user()->id;
    $auth = auth()->user();
    $liked = like_video::with('amvs')->where("user_id", "=", $id)->latest();
    return view("amvs.likedvideos", [
        'liked' => $liked,
        'auth' => $auth,
    ]);
}
```

I used model relationship on Amv Model

```
public function amvs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\like_video');
}
```

This is my view file

```
@foreach ($liked->amvs as $amv)
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="{{url("amvtube/watch/$amv->id")}}" class="text-decoration-none">
                        <div class="card mb-2 rounded-0" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="{{asset('/image/'.$amv->thumb)}}" alt="thumbnail" width="286px" height="161px">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{Str::limit($amv->title, 40, '...')}}</h5>
                                <span class="card-text">{{$amv->user->name}} / Genre: {{$amv->category->name}}</span> <br>
                                <span class="text-muted">
                                    {{$amv->view}} View {{$amv->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) `Laravel Docs` Read this.The foreignId method creates an UNSIGNED BIGINT equivalent column, while the constrained method will use conventions to determine the table and column name being referenced. If your table name does not match Laravel's conventions, you may specify the table name by passing it as an argument to the constrained method.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

Add this to your Contoller:

```
public function likedvideo() {
$id = auth()->user()->id;
$data["auth"] = auth()->user();
$data["liked"] = Amv::with('liked_videos')->where("user_id", "=", $id)->get();
return view("amvs.likedvideos",$data);
```

}

This to `Amv` model:

```
public function liked_videos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\like_video', 'amv_id', 'id');
}
```

IN VIEW:

```
var_dump($liked);die();

@foreach ($liked as $amv)
<div class="col">
    <a href="{{url("amvtube/watch/$amv->id")}}" class="text-decoration-none">
        <div class="card mb-2 rounded-0" style="width: 18rem;">
             <img src="{{asset('/image/'.$amv->thumb)}}" alt="thumbnail" width="286px" height="161px">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{Str::limit($amv->title, 40, '...')}}</h5>
                <span class="card-text">{{$amv->user->name}} / Genre: {{$amv->category->name}}</span> <br>
                <span class="text-muted">
                    {{$amv->view}} View {{$amv->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

@endforeach

Comment: This didn't work. The error remains the same "(

Comment: Errors cleared but no liked videos are being showned

Comment: that because you haven't define vidoe tag for the video in your view :
add video tag in your blade.php add this to it`s src  `{{$amv->video}}`

Comment: Like this:
`<video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="{{URL::asset("/path_to_your_video/$amv->video")}}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

Comment: no i mean the cards that will redirect to liked videos aren't getting displayed.

Comment: Dose it show `title` ,  `created_at` data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248703/discussion-between-thant-htet-aung-and-abdullah-afridi).

Answer (score 0):

The foriegn key in your like_videos is wrong.
The format that Laravel looks for by default is table name with id appended.

```
Schema::create('like_videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId("amvs_id");
        $table->foreignId("user_id");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: I changed, migrate fresh but still the error remains

Comment: okay wait let me recreate it.
can you share your error?

Comment: Property [amvs] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\amvtube\resources\views\amvs\likedvideos.blade.php)

Comment: what is your `amvs` modal class name?

Comment: if your're asking about amvs table then class name of Amv model is just "Amv".

Answer (score 0):

mention the error laravel app is showing?
possible that your `users` table has `id` and you're using `foreignId('user_id')` which model can't find so use same name as `id()` field with your `foreignId()` fields or make relations as:

`$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`

then connect with foreign:

`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('Users');`

**MODIFY TABLE SCHEMA LIKE THIS:**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('sub');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('suspend');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('amvs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('desc');
        $table->integer('view');
        $table->integer('like');
        $table->integer('dislike');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->contrained('users');
        $table->string('video');
        $table->string('thumb');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('like_videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId("amv_id")->constrained('amvs');
        $table->foreignId("user_id")->constrained('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });``
```

Comment: it didn't work. the error remains the same

Comment: which one did you tried can you tell?

Comment: I tried changing the foreignid to be the same as table name but it give me more errors when i tried to access other pages. I can't figure out why these errors pop up even tho there's no relations between these two pages - _ -

Comment: If your table name does not match Laravel's conventions, you may specify the table name by passing it as an argument to the constrained like this:
     ``$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');`` specify the table name in constrained.

Comment: I did that to user_id and amv_id both. But still the error remains "(

Comment: kindly mention your error. and if it is coming while you're migrating or when on view

Comment: It's in view i guess....there's no problem in migrating. I also found where the error located. If I commented that out, the errors clears but original error "Property [amvs] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\amvtube\resources\views\amvs\likedvideos.blade.php)" remains the same